# Kubernetes SQL Server or Azure SQL Server PaaS

Tags: sql-server, azure, docker, azure-aks

I'm attempting to ask this to garner non opinion based answers, as there doesn't appear to be a huge amount of official literature on the subject.

In what situations would you prefer say an Azure Kubernetes Service hosted SQL Server container over an Azure Sql Server (PaaS) offering?

In my mind it's when you want your whole world containerised and lean upon the versioning possibilities e.g. to have multiple versions live at the same time.

However I find it off putting hosting SQL Server even in a container it feels reminiscent of IaaS without the comfort blanket of PaaS.

Does AKS + SQL Containers offer sufficient ease that you can live the "container dream" or alternatively can Azure SQL PaaS sit nicely within a container offering?

In an attempt to make this non-opinionated can people supply scenarios or authoritative references?
Or of course if *you* are an authoritative reference even better!

Comment: The SQL Server linux distribution has a lot of new issues so thats something to keep in mind if you want to run it in a container, The windows version is a mature product (battle tested). With the PaaS offering MSFT allows you to don't know anything a DBA knows, it does backup and restores, has index recommendation,  that a container doesn't have. You don't spend time patching, Azure SQL also has a different feature set then a SQL Server (e.g.: Accelerated database Recovery)

Comment: I agree if you have a specific need and that need cannot be fixed with Azure SQL PaaS then either go with SQL Server on a VM or a Container, just so many things you have to do with a production DB to make sure it is secure, it is HA, you have BCDR strategy in-place, and it can scale up and out very fast plus all the other daily DBA stuff. Azure SQL PaaS just takes care of it for you then why would you want a headache. If you have something in place and you think that caanot be done using Azure SQL PaaS then mention it.

Comment: @HassanRaza I agree. Unless you have a specific need, Kubernetes is far more complicated that PaaSso why invite the trouble. Also, something I can't confirm, but I don't think Kubernetes SQL supports AAD authentication (conversely, PaaS doesn't support  windows authentication, although it effectively supports single sign on)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll formulate my comment as answer.

#### Azure SQL Databases

Is a service that takes care of the hard parts of managing a database for you.
Including:

- Backup & Restores
- High Availability
- Data replication
- Scaling
- Choosing the right hardware
- Always up to date, if a new version rolls out, you can increase the compatibily level and you can use new features
- Security
- Azure AD Integration
- Index recommendations
- Elastic pools
- Azure support
- Licensing

What you can't do in Azure SQL Databases:

- CLR: Loading custom .NET code, that you can execute from SQL Server.
- Trace flags
- SQL Agent jobs ([Elastic database jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/job-automation-overview#elastic-database-jobs-preview) are in preview)
- Change Data Capturing (cdc)
- Cross database transactions
- Database Mail
- Attach Database
- `BACKUP` or `RESTORE` statements
- Altering Collation
- Mirroring
- Snapshots
- Some DBCC Statements
- Some DMV's
- Linked servers
- Minimal logging in bulk import
- OpenQuery/OpenDataSource
- Resource Governor
- Service Broker
- ...

See [this comparison between Azure SQL Databases and Azure SQL Managed instances.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/features-comparison)

[List of T-SQL differences](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/azure-sql/database/transact-sql-tsql-differences-sql-server)

#### Containerized SQL Server

You are limited to run a linux version of SQL Server. Which still has a high number of issues. All the things Azure takes care of, you need to do your self. It's quite new, so you may be hitting issues that nobody has seen before, the community however is growing. You also need to buy a SQL Server license.

**When should you use containerized SQL Server?**
You want to be cloud agnostic, to be able to switch cloud providers.

At the moment I wouldn't want to run a production workload on a containerized SQL Server. When SQL Server Linux gets mature this will change.

Comment: How much has Containerized SQL Server matured since your answer? Any major issues running dockerized SQL Server backing a production workload these days?

Comment: I still haven't encountered a dockerize SQL Server in production. It does has it use in development/testing stages.